# MacBookPro Desktop Screen Display Action

Tags: display, windows, screen

I need to know how to keep open windows from disappearing while working with one or more programs.  It seems like they vanish when I linger the cursor too long on one or the other but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this in preferences.  For instance - I'm needing to keep my browser open for reference while I'm typing something in Pages.  Even if I minimize the browser, it will still disappear in some cases.  Of course clicking on the icon in the desktop bar will reopen the browser where it was, but then the Pages window disappears, etc.  I need them to stay open simultaneously.  What to do?  MacBookPro is Retina, 15 inch, mid 2014 with Mojave 10.14.4.  Thanks.

Comment: You may need to use paragraph breaks and clarify your description. Formatting would help, but I still can't figure out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I'm just trying to keep more than one window open on my desktop at a time - like 2 side by side - and getting them to stick instead one vanish - swiped to the side.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I just found an article on "Split View" on Mac that is supposed to do what I want.  I'll try that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to change a setting of your Dock!
Or do you maybe have an app to organise your desktops or not?

I just remember this: click on the green circle top left corner (button to go full screen) but you hold the command key down while clicking and dragging the window to the left or right and normaly, it will set the window of your app to go from the left/right of your screen to the middle of your screen.
Do the same for another app but got the other direction. :-)
I don't know if this is understandable? :-(

Comment: No, I don't have an app that I'm aware of to do this.  Am I supposed to with this version of OS?  If not, can you recommend one - preferably free or low cost?

Comment: No, not at all, I was just curious because I had a similar experience with an app I had to manage the desktops.

Comment: Thanks, Dakta.  I just found an article on Split View that may be helpful.  :)

Comment: That's what I was explaining, I did not remember how that was called!
Nice that your issue is solved!

Comment: You are welcome!